# google cloud error reporting not able to collect errors properly from cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-error-reporting

by default all errors on cloud run is collected by cloud error reporting and it's working for me. but the traceback is not full.

by digging in the log from cloud run, i am able to get the full error log but it is really hard to get the context from the google cloud reporting alone.

this is what an error looks like in error reporting.
[image: stack trace on cloud error reporting]

this is the log on gcloud logging
[image: error on logging]

how to make cloud error reporting to able to collect the complete stack trace for an error?

Answer (score 0):

As of the moment, only [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/viewing-errors) can display the full stack trace when deploying a project and an error was encountered. I also see the stack trace when deploying it immediately when using Google Cloud Shell as well.

On Logs Explorer, there's no available option to view the full stack track as of the moment. We could only view the labels (e.g., instance ID, log name, timestamp), resources (e.g., database ID, project ID, project type, severity, etc.).

I would suggest to file this as a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for future updates. Please be advised that this doesn't have as specific ETA however you can keep track of its progress once the ticket has been created.